# lpr ignores options specified by -o

Tags: printing, cups, lpr

When submitting a text file to a printer (HP Color LaserJet 4650) from a Debian 8/`openbox` system, the `-p` or `-o prettyprint` option is ignored. Printing the same file from a MacOS X system produces a document with proper `-p` formatting. I am trying to identify the source of the problem on the linux system. A question posted [elsewhere](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/289883) noted that placement of the characters `/*` at the beginning of the file could resolve problems with the `-p` option, but this had no effect in my situation. I doubt, but do not exclude, the possibility of a bug in the edition of `CUPS` packaged with Debian 8. Alternatively, the source could be an absent or incorrect printer driver. How can the failure to use the `-p` option be explained? What firmware, software, configuration files, etc should be checked?

**Edit 1:** I should note that in addition Unix-style newline characters (`\n`) are ignored by the printer and must be replaced by Windows-style newline characters (`\r\n`) by, e.g., `awk 'sub("$", "\r")'`. This suggests that the underlying issue may relate to the printer driver, since the printer apparently expects `\r\n` whereas `lpr` sends documents with `n` alone.

**Edit 2:** The problem seems more general than originally indicated. Several other options (`-o landscape`, `-o scaling=100`) are also ignored for text or postscript files. While I haven't exhaustively tried all `lpr` options, it seems safe to conclude that the entire set of available options is being ignored.